# Copy record if it reoccures in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have two Excel workbooks where first has more records than a second one. There are multiple records that occur in both of them but not all of them. I am supposed to take out ones that reoccur in both of those workbooks. As I have never done any VBA much therefore I am writing in a C/C++ way which is not really accurate. Anyways, here is the code:

```
Sub roznica()

Dim sourceSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim sourceSheet2 As Worksheet
Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastLineSS1 As Integer
Dim LastLineSS2 As Integer
Dim LastLineDS As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Set sourceSheet1 = Workbooks("EU-Szczecin.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sourceSheet2 = Workbooks("Lista.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set destSheet = Workbooks("Szczecin-lista.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastLineSS1 = sourceSheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastLineSS2 = sourceSheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastLineDS = destSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To LastLineSS1
    For j = 2 To LastLineSS2
        If sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = sourceSheet2.Cells(j, 1).Value & sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = sourceSheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value Then
            destSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value
            destSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value

        End If
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

If values on A and B matches then macro should put those into third workbook. I checked if values reoccure and they do so logically program should pass if statement but it does not

Comment: Do you need VBA for This? You could copy the record from the lesser data to a new worksheet and then use Vlookup formula to find what is present in the other file. After that simply filter on `#N/A` and delete them?

Comment: I do need VBA as I will extend it later on.

Comment: In that case do the above in VBA. No Need to loop :) THis method is faster. Record a macro and see what do you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an If-clause, to get a logical `and` you have to use `AND` in VBA. So replace

`If sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = sourceSheet2.Cells(j, 1).Value & sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = sourceSheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value Then`

with

`If sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = sourceSheet2.Cells(j, 1).Value AND sourceSheet1.Cells(i, 2).Value = sourceSheet2.Cells(j, 2).Value Then`

There are some operators that are handled differently from high-level languages. Instead of `!` you use `NOT`, instead of `== null` you use `Is Nothing` and, as you have experienced by now, no semicolons. To extend a line, use `_`.

The `&` operator stands for string concatenation by the way.